# 2 satisfiability strongly connected components topological ordering

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, 2-satisfiability

I'm solving a two-satisfiability problem with SCCs, and have a question about topological sorting. The algorithm I'm basing this on is to process SCCs in reverse topological order, which is fine when they're all connected. My algorithm is breaking on cases like this:

```
3 3
-2 3
1 -2
-2 -1
```

This makes a graph that looks like this:
[image: Graph of problem]

There are two sources and two sinks in this graph, and depending on where you start there are multiple topological sorts, so there are two possible final nodes. There are no cycles so each node is an SCC. There are multiple paths from source to sink, so when I do reverse topological order I can either start at sink x3 or sink !x2. The path that will give me a correct answer is to start at !x2, which will result in 1, -2, -3 or -1, -2, -3, both of which are solutions. But if I start at x3, one possible outcome is -1, 2, 3, which is not a solution.

So when I look at my two sinks, how do I decide topologically which is last? Clearly the answer is !x2, but I'm trying to figure out how the algorithm will determine that. I see four possible ideas:

- !x2 is last because it has more nodes leading into it
- !x2 is last because it is at the end of a longer path
- Set the truth value of each of the sinks before I start processing anything
- There is no way to know which is last, so create all possible solutions and test each of them to see if it works.

Or is there something about topologically ordering SCCs I'm not getting here? This is based on the algorithm I used to pass a Strongly Connected Components assignment in an earlier course, so it can't be completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I can't be sure, but my guess is that  when you process the literals you're setting a value and then flipping it later when you encounter its negation deeper in the topological order.  The key is that once you set a variable, you don't change it again.  Skip the literal of any variable that already has a set value.

Edited to add: From your comment I think I see the problem.  You mention setting the variable x2 to true when !x2 comes first in the reverse topological sort.  You should be setting the *literal* !x2 to true, which means you set the *variable* x2 to false.  If you do that, then your solver should work not matter which of the sinks you start with.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't include my code because it's pretty long and this is more a theoretical question, but I am not flipping the digits. I'm skipping anything that's already been set. What the algorithm did was process x3 true and !x3 false, then x2 true and !x2 false. Then it started at the other sink, !x2, but that was already set false before so it was skipped, then went backwards to !x1 and set that true and x1 false, then stopped, resulting in -1 2 3. So you can see by following the rules you're describing I'm led to a wrong answer.

Comment: @jimboweb Edited the answer based on new information, hope it helps.